# Twitter API - Search latin special characters

Tags: twitter

How can I perform a search in Twitter API that matches with special chars like Ñ or Ç?

Even web search seems to be confused with those characters

Ex:
`https://twitter.com/search?q=u%C3%B1as&src=typd`

It returns a list of tweets matching with 'unas' and 'uñas', and the same result is returned if an API search is performed

And it happens in inverse way, if you search 'barca' twitter will return tweets matching with 'barça' and 'barca'

The only way I found to ensure that the keyword, and only the keyword, is in tweets, is a programming filtering when results are fetched. Is there any better way?